# Solving system of linear equations, constraining the results between 0 and 1

Tags: r, linear-algebra, linear-programming

I'm trying to solve the following system of equations:

```
x1 + x2 + x3 = 1
0.5 * x1 + 0.75 * x2 + 0.25 * x3 = 0.25
```

I first randomly select $x3$ from a uniform distribution. Then I update my system of equations to solve for the remaining x1 and x2. However, I want to make sure that x1 and x2 are also between 0 and 1. Currently, solving the above example of system of equations results in a negative x1 and an x2 that is greater than 1. Is there a way to incorporate this constraint somehow?

```
library(matlib)
set.seed(3)
x3 <- runif(1, 0.01, 0.99)
A <- matrix(c(1, 2/4, 1, 3/4), 2, 2)
b <- c(1 - x3, 0.25 - 1/4 * x3)
showEqn(A, b)
> Solve(A, b)
x1    =  -0.34936139 
x2  =    1.1746807
```

Comment: why not use a LP solver?

Comment: @qwr Could you show me an example? Is this in the `lpSolve` package?

Comment: I haven't used it myself but that is a reasonable place to start

Comment: @qwr, I'm playing around with it, but it requires the user to define an objective function (to maximize or minimize), however, I can't really see what objective function I have here (I'm not trying to maximize or minimize anything).

Comment: Specify the same equation to minimize and maximize simultaneously. Your solution is the intersection of two planes which should be a line, limited in coordinates.

Comment: I suggest reading Wikipedia page on Linear Programming for some basics.

Comment: Thanks. Have you used any LP solver R packages? I am trying to specify the same eqn to maximize and minimize simultaneously using the `lpSolve` package, but I'm not sure that it can be done. If you've used other R packages, I'd be happy to try.

Comment: No I have never used a LP solver, though I will try someday. lpSolve appears to support both directions of constraints (max and min) but recall trivially max x is the same as min -x. See lpSolve docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of the two linear equations is the intersection of two planes which is a line. Then any value on the line which satisfies x1 and x2 constraints is valid. In this case, `x2 = -x1/2` and `x3 = 1 - x1/2` so the only solution is `(x1, x2, x3) = (0, 0, 1)`.

If you want **symbolic solutions** than R is probably not the right choice. Instead use a CAS like Mathematica or a constraint satisfier to determine the feasibility region:

```
Solve[x1 + x2 + x3 == 1 && 0.5 x1 + 0.75 x2 + 0.25 x 3 == 0.25 && 0 <= x1 <= 1 && 0 <= x2 <= 1, {x1,x2,x3}, Reals]
```

Output

```
{{x1 -> 0, x2 -> 0, x3 -> 1.}}
```

If your constraints did not have a unique solution, for example `-1 <= x2 <= 1`, you would get a result like

```
{{x1 -> ConditionalExpression[1. - 1. x2 - 1. (1. + x2), -0.5 <= x2 <= 0], 
  x3 -> ConditionalExpression[1. + x2, -0.5 <= x2 <= 0]}}
```

Instead if you want **one numerical solution** then a LP solver is good for this task. Since you are not maximizing or minimizing anything then any solution satisfying the constraints will work. Here I "maximize" a zero objective function to obtain any solution.

```
library(lpSolve)

#     x1 +      x2 +      x3 =  1
# 0.5 x1 + 0.75 x2 + 0.25 x3 =  0.25
#     x1                     >= 0
#     x1                     <= 1
#               x2           >= 0
#               x2           <= 1

f.obj <- c(0, 0, 0)
f.con <- matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.75, 0.25, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), nrow=6, byrow=TRUE)
f.dir <- c("=", "=", ">=", "<=", ">=", "<=")
f.rhs <- c(1, 0.25, 0, 1, 0, 1)

lp ("max", f.obj, f.con, f.dir, f.rhs)$solution
```

Output

```
[1] 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

With two equations for two remaining variables, the result is unique if the equations are independent, so you can't constrain the result.

What you can do is to solve your equation analytically and find where `x1`, `x2` and `x3` are between 0 and 1 in the solution set.

Otherwise, you can keep your approach and check at the end if `x1` and `x2` are between 0 and 1. If not, you can repeat the operation (e.g you put your code in a `while(TRUE)` loop and you `break` when you have found a suitable solution). However, if you do that, you should set a limit of iteration, otherwise your code might run indefinitely if no solution exist in the range you want.

Comment: Do you know what package I can use to solve my equations analytically?

Comment: I would way paper and pencil ;) otherwise you can try https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-r-as-a-computer-algebra-system-with-ryacas/

Comment: The solution is the intersection of two planes which is a line. Then any value on the line which satisfies x1 and x2 constraints is valid. There is no need to do any iterative algorithms.

Comment: Yes: if you want the constraint 0<z<1 and the same for x and y and use the proposed approach (pick a random z and find corresponding x and y) you need iteration to find x and y fitting in the given boundaries (if exists). For sure you can also find the equation of the line, as I say in the answere